# upload file using POSTMAN to Spring MVC 3.0.x

Tags: java, spring, upload, postman

Be frank and straight.

Trying to code a controller on Spring 3.0.6, and testing on it with POSTMAN.

I found that if I submit file with POSTMAN with config like this:

```
{
Headers:{
enctype :multipart/form-data
}
Body:{
(form-data) 'filename': '__file_path__'
}}
```

**And then I cannot handle it in MVC**;

While I code MVC like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "uploadModelXlsFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadModelXlsFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
```

**And then I cannot upload file in POSTMAN.**

In one word, I had not found a way to combine these two component yet.

So Im looking for help here, please any one get idea help me.

Thanks you very much reading this post. Best wishes and good life.

Comment: What do you want to do with the file once you have uploaded it?  Store it on the filesystem for later retrieval?  Store it in a database?  Something else?

Comment: @PaulWarren I will analyze the file, use the data inside. Now i have found the solution, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, its done.

on a java project like mine, you need to add some lines to the xml config file.

Add to file (WEB-INF/spring-mvc.xml) these lines:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"  
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />  
</beans>
```

And then every thing goes right.